# Libxml program in CPP

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ubuntu

I have wrote a program in C++ that demonstrate the use of libxml2.The code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
void parseStory (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur) {
 xmlChar *key;
cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
while (cur != NULL) {
    if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"keyword"))) {
        key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
        printf("keyword: %s\n", key);
        xmlFree(key);
    }
cur = cur->next;
}
return;
}

static void parseDoc(char *docname) {

xmlDocPtr doc;
xmlNodePtr cur;

doc = xmlParseFile(docname);

if (doc == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
    return;
}

cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

if (cur == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"empty document\n");
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return;
}

if (xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "story")) {
    fprintf(stderr,"document of the wrong type, root node != story");
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return;
}

cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
while (cur != NULL) {
    if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"storyinfo"))){
        parseStory (doc, cur);
    }

cur = cur->next;
}

xmlFreeDoc(doc);
return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

char *docname;

if (argc <= 1) {
    printf("Usage: %s docname\n", argv[0]);
    return(0);
}

docname = argv[1];
parseDoc (docname);

return (1);
 }
```

I am using Ubuntu and I have installed libxml2-dev package and compile with

```
g++ Libxml2Example.cpp -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -lxml2 -o output
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Build of configuration Debug for project Libxml2Example ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Libxml2Example.cpp
 Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Libxml2Example.d" -      MT"src/Libxml2Example.d" -o"src/Libxml2Example.o" "../src/Libxml2Example.cpp"
../src/Libxml2Example.cpp:12:30: fatal error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or     directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/Libxml2Example.o] Error 1
```

How to solve this error?please help me.

Comment: Which OS do you use? You need to add -I in compile.

Comment: i am running this in ubuntu

Comment: Please pardon me, but isn't using `#include <stdio.h>` in `c++`is non-conventional? IMHO, you should consider using `#include <cstdio>`.

Answer (score 1):

The directory `libxml` must exist either within an existing implicitly searched include path specified by any of the following environment variables:

```
CPATH
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
GCC_INCLUDE_DIR
```

or its path must be explicitly specified by `-I.

I am willing to bet that after compilation, you will have a similar problem with linking, finding the libxml.a file, for which a `-L<path>` setting will be required or setting the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH`.

Generally the environment variable approach should probably be avoided in order to make your project and its build files portable to other installations without having to set up the build environment.

Comment: iam compiling it using the following command                        g++ Libxml2Example.cpp -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -lxml2 -o output      now iam getting this error:fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @Chinnu just remove last `libxml` of your compile command. This directory command is included in `#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>`

Comment: @Chinnu : That's a different question.  Either update this question, or start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install development package of libxml2

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

This will install libraries `include` files.

In your project you need to compile with `-I/usr/include/libxml2/`

ie

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall ../src/Libxml2Example.cpp -I/usr/include/libxml2/ -lxml2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

In x86_64 ubuntu systems the libraries are installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

Comment: but while executing this command a.out file is not produced instead one .o file is created why??

Comment: @Chinnu you should remove `-c`. This flag creates only the object file. I edited...